# How to make python recognize saved variables randomly selected from external file

Tags: python, random

I have a program which randomly selects and prints song names and artists from an external text file. 
I have split the line into an a,b format but the program won't recognize the variable once i answer the question.

```
file = open("Songz.txt", "r")

lines = file.readlines()

random_lines = random.choice(open("Songz.txt").readlines())

Song = random_lines

a,b=(Song.split(","))
print(a)
print(b)

Answer1 = input().upper()

if Answer1 == b:
        print(" Correct ")
        Quiz_Score = Quiz_Score + 3
else:
        print("incorrect")
```

Once the code reaches the 
`if Answer1 == b:`

section, the code seems to forget what value the variable (b) has. Any ideas why?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You forgot the trailing newline on `b`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the data you read from file.
In fact, the list you get with the `readlines` method will have extra `\n` symbols in the end

```py
['SONG1, ANSWER1\n', 'SONG2, ANSWER2\n', 'SONG3, ANSWER3\n']
```

So you need to clean them up by using `strip()`:

```py
with open("Songz.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

random_line = random.choice(lines)

a, b = random_line.split(",")
print(a)
print(b)

answer1 = input().upper()

# strip() will take care of the '\n' and the surrounding spaces if any
if answer1 == b.strip():
    print(" Correct ")
    quiz_score += 3
else:
    print("incorrect")
```

Comment: Is there a reason the file is opened and read twice?  Meaning why not random_lines = random.choice(lines)

Comment: Definitely not, it was a copy-paste from the original post. I'll make an edit.